# fb-comment fluid with warpper container by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, wordpress

I am installing the fb-comment to my wordpress, with the need of comment management I found the below code. It works well, but the problem is the fixed width.

Few points to notice:

- I set the blank width, it gets default 550px (decent)
- So do I delete  `data-width='"+width+"'` in the php, still that width
- Tried a lot of css solution, the width remains

So I am thinking a straight forward way to **bind the width value to a warpper container div by jquery**. And this is my question.

```
(function () {
        var admins = 614590779, // admin ID
        app_id = 291027061045087, // app ID

        width = "", // width

        numposts = 5, // comment to show
        fbLocation = ".comments", // where to place the fb-comment 
        color = "light", // theme
        postUrl = "<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>";
        //<![CDATA[
        var cb=function(){postUrl=(postUrl.search("http")<0)?"http://"+location.hostname+location.pathname:postUrl;jQuery("head").prepend("<meta content='"+admins+"' property='fb:admins'></meta><meta content='"+app_id+"' property='fb:app_id'></meta>");jQuery(function(){jQuery("body").prepend("<div id='fb-root'></div><sc"+"ript>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+app_id+"'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</sc"+"ript>");jQuery(fbLocation).prepend("<div class='fb-comments' data-colorscheme='"+color+"' data-numposts='"+numposts+"' data-width='"+width+"' href='"+postUrl+"'></div>");FB.XFBML.parse()})};var getScript=function(url,cb){var script=document.createElement("script");if(script.readyState){script.onreadystatechange=function(){if(script.readyState=="loaded"||script.readyState=="complete"){script.onreadystatechange=null;if(cb){cb()}}}}else{script.onload=function(){if(cb){cb()}}}script.src=url;document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)};if(typeof jQuery==="undefined"){getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js",cb)}else{cb()};
        //]]>
        } )();
```

Comment: What's the question!?

Comment: bind the width value to a warpper container div(id/ class) by jquery

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it resize as you shrink the window, but I can set it to the width of the page when it loads:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var width = $('div.container').width();
    $('div.fb-comments').attr('data-width', width);
});
</script>
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned itand using this instead. This is capable for the latest update in 2014 march.

> $(window).bind("load", function() { 
>   $(".fb-comments").attr("data-width",
>   $(".fb-comments").parent().width()); $(window).on('resize', function()
>   { resizeFacebookComments(); });
>
> function resizeFacebookComments() { var src = $('.fb-comments
>   iframe').attr('src').split('width='),
>       width = $(".fb-comments").parent().width();
>
> $('.fb-comments iframe').attr('src', src[0] + 'width=' + width); } });